# T-typ neutral point inverter i want to draw the image using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, electronics

can anyone help me draw this circuit please
i need it urgently

[image]

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Welcome. // Please let us know the context wrt. Latex, preferably as EDIT to your question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick fix, which you can replace later by, e.g. a Tikz drawing, or by a schematic from some other CAD software, where I stored your graphics as `inverter.png` in the same directory:

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
 Here's just an included image:
 
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{inverter}
\end{document}
```